# Python Win32 send keystrokes to Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, winapi, winspector

I am trying to run a python script in Windows to send an `F5` command to a `Google Chrome v53` window. But unfortunately nothing happens. But it works like a charm with `Internet Explorer v11` (after changing the `Class Name`).

- [Winspector detects the `Class Name` of the Google Chrome window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llzHA.png)
- Python finds the window and sends the command
- No message gets logged as send to the process

Python code

```
import win32gui, win32api, win32con
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", None)
print hwnd
# Sending command to the main windows also does not work
win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_F5, 0)
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, None, "Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND", None)
print hwnd
win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_F5, 0)
```

Python output

```
1181972
0
```

---

**EDIT: Included hidden windows**

[There seems to be more windows, that have the same `Class Name`.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OPJD.png) Therefore, I am now searching not only by the `Class Name`, but also by the `Text`. The first attempt did only find a window, which did not have any children. Therefore the second line of the output had a `0`.

Altered Python code

```
import win32gui, win32api, win32con
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", "Stack Overflow - Google Chrome")
print hwnd
# Sending command to the main windows also does not work
win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_F5, 0)
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, None, "Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND", None)
print hwnd
win32api.PostMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_F5, 0)
```

Python output

```
1247302
1509536
```

---

**EDIT: `SetForegroundWindow` solution**

The solution for the problem was first to set the window to foreground by `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(Handle)` method and then to send the key commands.

But still, no commands are passed to the window and the website is not refreshed.

Comment: Might be related to the fact that Chrome runs every tab in a separate process.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: Thank you for the hint, I just updated my question. Unfortunately, it did not help.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using UI Automation to trigger the *Reload this page* button? The button shows up in the accessible tree, so it can be used with UI Automation.

Comment: @IInspectable: The solution for the problem was to set the window to foreground before sending commands (see the newest edit). I am actually working further with a CEF version of the browser and therefore, there are no accessible buttons for the automation. Therefore, I wanted to send the commands in the background.

Comment: I hope you understand the restrictions that apply, when a process can successfully call [SetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx). Also keep in mind, that you are **not** sending commands. You are faking input, and - as we all know - [you can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: @IInspectable: Of which restrictions are you talking about using SetForegroundWindow? The window is already in the foreground, so from that point of view, it is not a problem. And thanks for the reference to the blog thread!

Comment: There's an entire list of conditions, some of which need to be true at the same time (a long standing documentation bug, that implies, that meeting **any** single condition would be sufficient). Being the foreground process is not enough to successfully call `SetForegroundWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('f5')
```

This will simulate your refresh key, sending the signal to chrome.
In case you don't want the chrome window to be made active, then when you START chrome, start it by typing this in the command prompt:

```
start /B chrome.exe
```

Then close chrome. It will run in the background.  When the work is done, go Task Manager and close chrome.
OR you could go to Chrome>Advanced>System and see the first option.

Comment: How to send this keystroke specifically to the Chrome window, from a Python script (and possibly not change the focus to this window manually)?